# cURL request is not being sent in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get a basic cURL request to work.  I am running Wamp 2.5 and PHP 5.5.12. I've double checked the php.ini files and have made sure cURL was actually set up and ready to go. Here is my code:

```
$url = "https://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $status_code;
```

There is no error returned except "0", and if I do var_dump the result is "boolean false".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `curl_exec()` should be first

Answer (score 2):

Happens, a stupid mistake. Happens to all of us :-)

Try this:

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
echo $status_code;
```

The output is: `302`

You obviously *first* have to execute the request before you *then* can get its status code.

Comment: Sorry...I mean, even if I remove the whole status_code part, its not actually executing do you know what I mean?

Comment: @CodeTadpole It _does_ execute the request for me. The `302` _is_ the result of the request. What makes you think it does _not_ execute the request on your side?

Comment: Hmmm...that makes me wonder if something is indeed wrong in my setup somewhere. I even copied and pasted what you typed and status is still 0